# vb.net getting data from datatable using array

Tags: php, javascript, .net, vb.net, highcharts

am making a chart, using highcharts, code behind is vb.net...

i have a datatable that is something like this:

```
Date - speed - data
2011    10k     6
2011    18k     7
2012    20k     10
2012    10k      2
2013    14k      4
2013    20k      6
```

before when i wanted to get the datatble information for speed, i would use the following code:

```
 Dim a As DataSet = Cons
    Dim abc As DataTable
    abc = a.Tables(0)

 Dim array As New ArrayList

 For Each row In abc.Rows
        array.Add(row("Speed"))

    Next row

 Dim serializer As New JavaScriptSerializer()
  Dim arrayJson As String = serializer.Serialize(array)
```

so the code above will show me the data for speed.

however what if i want the data for 2011? or 2013. how would i get this, i have some code that has been done, but as i am using highchart i need to convert this in to array.

how would i change this:

```
For Each row In abc.Rows
        array.Add(row("Speed"))

    Next row
```

so that i can get the dates, any ideas anyone.

ok, but what if the year is the same, but day is diffrent,

so

```
01/10/2011 00:00:00
04/07/2011 00:00:00
21/11/2012 00:00:00
11/11/2013 00:00:00
```

so how do i call the date of 2011?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since 'abc' is a DataTable, you can use [DataTable.Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/det4aw50.aspx) method.

For example to get the data for year 2011:

```
For Each row In abc.Select("Date >= #1/1/2011# And Date <= #12/31/2011#")
  array.Add(row("Speed"))
Next row
```

Comment: ok, but what if the year is the same, but day is diffrent, 

so

    01/10/2011 00:00:00
    04/07/2011 00:00:00
    21/11/2012 00:00:00
    11/11/2013 00:00:00
so how do i call the date of 2011?

Comment: You should've mentioned that in your post. Please post correct date values. Also what DB you're using? SQL Server?

Comment: Assuming that it's a normal date field I've updated my answer.

Comment: So does the updated answer `"Date >= #1/1/2011# And Date <= #12/31/2011#"` work for u?

Comment: no, it wont because i have to many dates, i have some code that already defined this, e.g
Dim Year1 As System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection(Of DataRow)
year 1 shows the  specific data, but i cant call it

Dim a As DataSet = Year1

Year1 shows error

Comment: According to you, your data table list dates in one column called `Date`. It can have thousands of dates in that column, but to select all rows for a specific year you need to compare it to 2 dates only - year start and year end.